# get the request path in a spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I get the matched request path in an HTTP mapping method in a spring application? In the following example, I want `matchedPath` variable to have the value `/api/products/{product_id}/comments` which is a combination of `@RequestMapping` and `@PostMapping` value.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Example {

    @PostMapping("/products/{product_id}/comments")
    public ResponseEntity doSomething(@PathVariable("product_id") String id) {
        // String matchedPath = getPath();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry if my question seems silly. But why not manually add the path. The address is going to be static. You get product_id vis String 'id'. Why not merge them?

Comment: You can try the `HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`?

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to do with the path? Adding a parameter of `UriComponentsBuilder` is frequently the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I found it is doable via one of `HandlerMapping` attributes `BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Example {

    @PostMapping("/products/{product_id}/comments")
    public ResponseEntity doSomething(HttpServletRequest req, @PathVariable("product_id") String id) {
        String matchedPath = String.valueOf(req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html